# How to reach streaming learning in Neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

As title, I know there're some model supporting streaming learning like classification model. And the model has function `partial_fit()`

Now I'm studying regression model like SVR and RF regressor...etc in `scikit`.

But most of regression models doesn't support `partial_fit` .

So I want to reach the same effect in neural network. If in tensorflow, how to do like that? Is there any keyword?

Answer (score 0):

There is no some special function for it in TensorFlow. You make a single training pass over a new chunk of data. And then another training pass over another new chunk of data, etc till you reach the end of the data stream (which, hopefully, will never happen).

Comment: If I don't do that by a function, is there anyway to reach online learning effect?